# trying to add content to the middle of a string

Tags: geoprocessing, field-calculator

I am trying to add content to the middle of a string by using `MyStr = Mid([MyField], 1, 1)`  and I get an error.

I've tried `MyStr = Mid([_smallx], 63, 6)` and `MyStr = Mid(["_smallx"], 63, 6)`

The string is a file path totaling 76 characters and I need to add `_small` at 63 and keep the 13 characters at the end.

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE, can you give a visual example of the path, what you have and what you want?  Also, are you using ArcGIS?

Comment: \\gcsan2\dotdata\Kane County Images 2013\K001_NA\4G130514000219\4G000107.jpg  This is what I have and this is what I need: \\gcsan2\dotdata\Kane County Images 2013\K001_NA\4G130514000219_small\4G000107.jpg

Answer (score 2):

This is using Python:

```
def add_string(field):
  split_text = field.split("\\")
  split_text[6] = split_text[6] + "_small"
  return "\\".join(split_text)


add_string(yourField)
```

Just use it in the field calculator with Python as the parser and check show Codeblock.

[image]

Results:

[image]

Comment: I was able to accomplish this with using your example above.  Thank you.

Comment: No problem, glad it worked for you. I just realized I made a mistake, the text = field, is not needed but it will still work how it is.

Answer (score 1):

Mid will generally extract characters from your string, not add them in. To insert text in the middle of a string, you might do something like this (details would differ depending on language/environment):

```
Left(MyStr,63) & "_smallx" & Right(MyStr,13)
```

Comment: +1, but I think that you need single quote ' and not double quote "

Comment: Still received message failure during processing using double quotes and then trying single quotes

Comment: It would help if you could give more detail on how you're trying to do this. In ArcGIS or another program? With Python or a different language? Using Field Calculator?